# Equal distribution formula based on preset values. Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

e.g. There are 300 apples. There are 100 people. Each person has a preset value (represented as a number 1 to 5). 1=1 apple, if their value is 5 they get 5 apples etc. But there are 300 apples available so each person is going to get more then the value says they "deserve". Or one day there are only 200 apples and every one gets less then what the value states says they "deserve". Is this possible in excel?

NAME VALUE
john   5
james  5
sam    4
matt   5
mike   3
steve  2
etc...

Comment: A fairly simple approach would be to start with 0 apples each and randomly give apples to each person in proportion to their value until all apples are used up. This would give a solution, but I believe finding an optimal solution (and even defining what that would be) would be a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely sounds like a perfect  problem for Solver to handle. As you know, this in included within Excel's addins. It can deal with all the variables you mentioned.